# How to infer return type of a generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function that will always return a type, though it can change and defining it by hand would be some work and not scalable, so I'm trying to achieve this by using typescript's `infer` keyword

At first I saw  [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/8bgylq/28_infer_generic_type_it_finally_clicked/)
that uses

```js
type Foo<T> = T extends { a: infer U, b: infer U } ? U : never;
type T10 = Foo<{ a: string, b: string }>;  // string
type T11 = Foo<{ a: string, b: number }>;  // string | number
```

Problem is, my type is a generic function

Here is one minimal example,

```js
const fnFromLib = <T>(a: string, b: Record<string, string>) => {
  return function barFn(c: T) {
    return {
      c,
      b: b[a],
    };
  };
};
const foo = <T>(a: Record<string, string>) => {
  return {
    bar: fnFromLib<T>('foo', a),
  };
};
type returnTypeInferer<T> = T extends (a: Record<string, string>) => infer U ? U : never;
type fooType = typeof foo;
type fooReturnType = returnTypeInferer<fooType>;
```

there are no errors, but, since there was not a generic type being passed, `fooReturnType` will be inferred as

```js
type fooReturnType = {
    bar: (c: unknown) => {
        c: unknown;
        b: string;
    };
}
```

Noting that T from fnFromLib is not inferred from arguments and should be passed in the function call I try to pass on a type argument from `fooReturnType` to `fooType`, but that gives me a parsing error

```
type returnTypeInferer<T> = T extends (a: Record<string, string>) => infer U ? U : never;
type fooType<T> = typeof foo<T>; // ------   parsing error: ';' expected ---------
type fooReturnType<T> = returnTypeInferer<fooType<T>>;
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I want?

Thank you

Comment: Without something like [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) in TypeScript, I think you'll have to use workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managed to do it by wrapping the function into a generic class

```js
class GnClass<T> {
  foo = (a: Record<string, string>) => {
    return {
      bar: fnFromLib<T>('foo', a),
    };
  };
}
type returnTypeInferer<T> = T extends (a: Record<string, string>) => infer U ? U : never;
type fooType<T> = GnClass<T>['foo'];
type fooReturnType<T> = returnTypeInferer<fooType<T>>;
```

But I want to stick with functional programming, I will not mark this as accepted answer, will use it for now as I see no other alternative in the moment and would love another approach.

Comment: I think this is very clever and is probably one of the few ways (or maybe the only way) you can move a generic type parameter off of a function and into a value without wider support for [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  Also note that TypeScript provides `ReturnType<T>` as a utility type.

Comment: Thanks for the utility type tip :) maybe this is the only way, since I'm infering a type from an implemented generic function, so it must exist someway, if it was possible to get the type of the function as `typeof foo<T>` it would be great, but it is not...